# How to access files and phpmyadmin of a WordPress website in aws

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have installed WordPress using AWS Marketplace. Now I am looking to access my website files using ftp or cpanel and database using phpmyadmin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To access **WP** Files in **AWS** We can use Filezila

1.You can connect with FileZilla
[Download filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

2.Once Install go to:
Edit (Preferences) > Settings > Connection > SFTP, Click "Add key file”

3.Browse to the location of your .pem file and select it.

4.A message box will appear asking your permission to convert the file into ppk format. Click Yes, then give the file a name and store it somewhere.

5.If the new file is shown in the list of Keyfiles, then continue to the next step. If not, then click "Add keyfile..." and select the converted file.

6.File > Site Manager Add a new site with the following parameters:

**Host:** Your public dns name of ec2 instance, or the public ip address of the server

**Protocol:** SFTP(22)

**Logon Type:** Normal

**User:** From the docs: "For Amazon Linux, the default user name is ec2-user. For RHEL5, the user name is often root but might be ec2-user. For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu. For SUSE Linux, the user name is root. For Debian, the user name is admin. Otherwise, check with your AMI provider."

Press Connect Button - If saving of passwords has been disabled, you will be prompted that the logon type will be changed to 'Ask for password'. Say 'OK' and when connecting, at the password prompt push 'OK' without entering a password to proceed past the dialog.

**Note:** FileZilla automatically figures out which key to use. You do not need to specify the key after importing it as described above.

Comment: Great it works. I already can access files of my WordPress site. How can I access phpmyadmin of my WordPress database?

Comment: @FoisalMehedi Have lot of options to connect wordpress Database in AWS. U can Refer the below methods to connect [youtube.com/watch?v=Bz-4wTGD2_Q] refer below link to connect mysql DB using Putty method.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214883058-How-do-I-connect-to-my-database-using-a-third-party-program-

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this method as well. But when I enter the command [apt-get install apache2 php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php-ssh2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server php7.0-mysql git unzip zip postfix php7.0-curl mailutils php7.0-json phpmyadmin -y] 
it installs everything but the phpmyadmin configuration doesn't come up. What can I do?

Comment: @FoisalMehedi is that showing any error or else phpmyadmin page not loading ?

U can try below method it's aws official Link. hope u can get working.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: Its not working after adding https, how to resolve this?